# How to accurately benchmark a function that writes a file via mmap? Pauses later while printing, after the timed region?

Tags: c++, linux, benchmarking, mmap

I am trying to benchmark a public interface provided by someone else, which use `mmap` to write some in-memory object to disk. So i write such code snippet.

```cpp
void test(){
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    func_that_use_mmap_inside();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count();
    printf("duration: %.2f\n", duration);
}
```

This test function has some problems. When running it in my laptop, it gives a quite low output, like 20ms. But in fact the program stall many seconds before printing the duration, which is definitely much more than 20ms, and i'm pretty sure there are no operation other than `func_that_use_mmap_inside`.

I am guessing that the program behaviour is similar to call `msync` with `SYNC` symbol during the `main` clean up phase, thus explain the difference between low `printf` output and high actual time. If i can modify the `func_that_use_mmap_inside`, i can add a `msync` call to get the right result, but actually i can't. So how should i perform a "right" benchmark for `func_that_use_mmap_inside`?

Comment: Is that print going directly to a terminal, line buffered?  Have you tried warming up stdout before the timed region?  I wonder if lazy dynamic linking is somehow triggering write-back of the dirty data before printf can actually run.  Or maybe it's a matter of getting it actually output to the screen via your xterm or equivalent?  Might be interesting to try it on the text-mode console terminal where writes to the TTY will appear on screen without involving any pageable memory, just kernel TTY and video drivers.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for replying. The print did going directly to a line buffered terminal. I follow you suggestion and add some print statement before entering the timed region, but the situation seems remain.

Comment: `How to accurately benchmark a function ...` Regardless of how that continues, there isn't going to be a simple answer. Accurate benchmarking is hard.

Comment: @DavisHerring How can i know the exact start address and len?

Comment: @user8510613: Sorry, I was thinking of plain `sync` (which you *could* try); `msync` shouldn’t do any more than the `munmap` that’s presumably already in use.